# Optimize intersection of polygons

Tags: postgis, postgresql, intersection, spatial-database

I need to get the intersection of two polygons and both sides use the same dataset (`titlenumberpolygon` - UK National polygons). PostGIS is used in the analysis.

First a spatial index was created which took 27 mins. There are 30 million polygons.

```
CREATE INDEX geoid ON titlenumberpolygon USING GIST(geom)
```

The following code is used and for both the tables the polygon data is coming from titlenumberpolygon table.

```
SELECT tb2.UPRN,tb1.titleno
INTO AB_VOA_Onwer1
FROM ( 
    SELECT t1.titleno, tp.*
    FROM Ownership as t1
    INNER JOIN titlenumberpolygon as tp
    ON t1.titleno=tp.title_no) as tb1
INNER JOIN( 
    SELECT AU.UPRN,AU.Postcode,tp.*
    FROM AB_VOA_UPRN as AU
    INNER JOIN titlenumberpolygon as tp
    ON AU.inspiredid=tp.poly_id) as tb2    
 ON ST_Intersects(ST_MakeValid(tb1.geom),ST_MakeValid(tb2.geom));
```

It takes over 2 hours to run for one postcode and there are 500,000 postcodes in the table.

How can I optimise this code? Maybe a different spatial indexing method as I am using the same table in the intersection.

Comment: I think you need to use the  && operations to boost performance for bounding box. http://revenant.ca/www/postgis/workshop/indexing.html plus VACUUM your data.

Comment: the st_makevalid functions in the st_intersects is probably what is making the query either slow or not use the spatial index. is the make valid function necessary?

Comment: Do NOT use `ST_MakeValid` on each feature -- This forces a full table scan. If the features are not valid, you should fix that first (once, not with the use of every row).

Comment: Yes, putting functions in joins makes the query non-sargable, ie, no index can be used. Which data set is this, as a matter of interest. It sounds like one of the address ones.

Comment: Thanks everyone. It was the `ST_MakeValid` function made it much slower. But this query would run for about 2 days to get the results.

Comment: @ziggy I used `ST_MakeValid` because of this error `ERROR:  Relate Operation called with a LWGEOMCOLLECTION type.  This is unsupported.` But looks like `ST_MakeValid` is not the solution.

Comment: You problem then is that you have some geometry collections, so you need to do ST_CollectionExtract to just extract the polygons as well as, possibly,  ST_MakeValid, before running the actual query.

Answer (score 3):

The index cannot be used, because you're intersecting with modified fields, but the index only knows of the unmodified fields.

As @Vince said, your best option would be to fix the polygons of the tables before intersecting or at insert.

```
UPDATE titlenumberpolygon SET geom = ST_MakeValid(geom);
```

or

```
INSERT INTO titlenumberpolygon (geom) VALUES (ST_MakeValid(geom));
```

---

If that is not a possibility, you could create the indices including `ST_Make_Valid()`:

```
CREATE INDEX valid_geoid ON titlenumberpolygon USING GIST(ST_MakeValid(geom));
```

Comment: The technical term is non-sargable, see, for example, [this post](https://blog.bertwagner.com/how-to-search-and-destroy-non-sargable-queries-on-your-server-ff9f57c7268e). I love the word, and wish it were more commonly understood.

Comment: Thanks this is it and it is about sargable queries. But still this query would run for about 2 days to get the results.